Android Apps button showing contacts from social media
When I press the applications icon (circle with 6 dots) on Samsung Note20, I get a list of apps that are installed.  If I type in

S, I see contacts from Snapchat
L, I see contacts from Linkedin

Is there a way of stopping this lunacy.

In the search result, is there a "Search in app" label? If so, on the search bar, there's a 3-vertical dots on the right, then select "Choose apps to search in", and turn off the apps. At least that's how it works on Galaxy M12, Android 13, One UI 5.1

This is a feature of your launcher, so you have two options:

Open the settings page of your launcher (not the system settings app) and find an option to disable this behavior. (I don't have a Note 20, so I can't tell you exactly where that is.)
Install and set as default another launcher that doesn't do it by default. If you haven't tried another launcher before, I recommend doing it at least once, since you might find one that you like better.

